# Manipulating variables with excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Language: Excel

Hello & thank you for reading my post.

I am trying to create a formula to... multiply cells (or in this case letters) based upon variables. The variables being whether it is divisible by (1000 + 250x), and according to the answer, multiply it by the according *letter* percentage.

Visual representation:

```
   A     B     C   
   1%    2%    3%  
   250   500   1000  


1  1,000
2  1,250
3  1,500
4  1,750
5  2,000
```

For instance, since #1 is divisible by 1000, I would multiply it by 3%
Second instance, since #2 is divisible by 250, and 1000, I would multiply the 250 by 1% and the 1000 by 3%, and then add them together.

My current attempt:

```
=IF(MOD(A2,F14)<=1,A2*F15,"")
```

A2 =  the starting amount
F14 = what A2 is being divided by
F15 = the percentage

This kind of works, but it does not allow me to find the *best possible solution*.

Would greatly appreciate your help in my dilemma.

Comment: Mr Sparrow Please Improve your post by Editing

Comment: what do you mean as "best possible solution"?

Comment: What I mean by *best possible solution* @user3598756 ... For instance, take number 3 for example. It would not be ideal to take the 500 (from the 1500) total and divide it by 2, then multiply it by 1%, or in other words, take (((250 * 1%)*2)+(1000*3%)), INSTEAD, it would be much more ideal to do... ((500*2%) + (1000*3%))

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any good solution as of Excel formulas as the result you want is too complex: like you marked your question you need a loop, no matter what, which formulas cannot do for you I'm afraid.
But, as you added `VBA` as one of your tags, I assume a `VBA` solution would work for you, so here's the script I wrote:

```
Option Explicit 'variables MUST BE declared, otherwise error. very handy rule
Option Base 0 'won't be needed this time, but in general, this rule is also a great ally
              '(it says: arrays' 1st item will always be the "0th" one)

Dim divLARGE, divMED, divSMALL    'you can use variable types in Excel
Dim percLARGE, percMED, percSMALL 'but sadly, not in VBScript which I have ATM

'test input values and their results, won't be needed in your Excel
Dim testA, testB, testC, testD, testE, testF 'so add types if you like
Dim  resA,  resB,  resC,  resD,  resE,  resF '(should make execution a little faster)

'Init our variables declared above. in VBScript you can't do this at declaration,
'i.e. can't say "Dim whatever As Boolean = true" which would be the right way to do this
Call Initialize()

'Call the "main routine" to execute code
Call Main()

'you can add access modifiers here. "private" would be the best
'i.e. "private Sub Main()"
Sub Main()
     resA = CalcMaster(testA, divLARGE)
     resB = CalcMaster(testB, divLARGE)
     resC = CalcMaster(testC, divLARGE)
     resD = CalcMaster(testD, divLARGE)
     resE = CalcMaster(testE, divLARGE)
     resF = CalcMaster(testF, divLARGE)
     MsgBox (CStr(testA) + " --> " + CStr(resA) + vbCrLf + _
             CStr(testB) + " --> " + CStr(resB) + vbCrLf + _
             CStr(testC) + " --> " + CStr(resC) + vbCrLf + _
             CStr(testD) + " --> " + CStr(resD) + vbCrLf + _
             CStr(testE) + " --> " + CStr(resE) + vbCrLf + _
             CStr(testF) + " --> " + CStr(resF) + vbCrLf)
End Sub

Sub Initialize()
     divLARGE  = 1000 'the large number for which we look after remnants
     divMED    = 500  'medium/middle sized number to divide by
     divSMALL  = 250  'the small value
     percLARGE = 3    'percentage we want if no remnants on LARGE number
     percMED   = 2    'same but for medium/mid size numbers
     percSMALL = 1    'and the percentage we want for the small remnants

     testA=1000 'result should be exactly 30.0
     testB=1250 'res == 32.5
     testC=1500 'res == 40.0
     testD=1750 'res == 42.5
     testE=2000 'res == 60.0
     testF=-198 'res == #ERROR/INVALID VALUE
End Sub

Function CalcMaster(inVar, byDiv) 'A silly function name popped in my mind, sorry :)
Dim remnant, percDiv
     'sometimes happens, looks cheaper calc.wise to handle like this; if initial input
     'can be 0 and that's a problem/error case, handle this scenario some other way
     If (inVar = 0) Then Exit Function
     remnant = inVar Mod byDiv
     'if you'll implement more options, do a Select...Case instead (faster)
     If (byDiv = divLARGE) Then
          percDiv = percLARGE
     ElseIf (byDiv = divMED) Then
          percDiv = percMED
     Else
          percDiv = percSMALL
     End If


     If (remnant = 0) Then
          CalcMaster = inVar * (percDiv / 100)
      Exit Function
     End If
     'had remnant; for more than 3 options I would use an array of options
     'and call back self with the next array ID
     If (byDiv = divLARGE) Then
          CalcMaster = CalcMaster(inVar - remnant, divLARGE) + CalcMaster(remnant, divMED)
     ElseIf (byDiv = divMED) Then
          CalcMaster = CalcMaster(inVar - remnant, divMED) + CalcMaster(remnant, divSMALL)
     Else 'or return 0, or raise error and handle somewhere else, etc
          'MsgBox ("wrong input number: " + CStr(inVar))
      CalcMaster = -1
     End If
End Function
```

It's not perfect, I assume there could be better solutions out there but I think it's good enough for the cause. I hope you agree :)
Cheers

Comment: I had marked VBA as a possible solution, even though I lack experience in the area. I believe I will be able to pick it up fairly quickly due to your annotations and my prior coding experience. Since, you have taken the time to write a code for me, I shall reciprocate your kindness by taking the time to dissect it and learn it.
Thank you so much Mark!

Comment: @Sparrow You're welcome! If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask. Thank you in advance for marking my answer as solution if and when you was able to put it together with your actual Excel and sorted out the issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

after Sparrow explanation I got that the "best possible solution" is the one that maximizes the "total prize" obtained by multiplying all possible whole divisors (i.e. 250, 500, 1000) by their correspondent "prize"(1%, 2%, 3%)

here's a consequent solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim dataRng As Range, cell As Range, percRng As Range, divRng As Range
Dim i As Long, value As Long, nDivisors As Long
Dim prize As Double, totalPrize As Double

Set dataRng = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B10") '<== here set the range cointaining the numbers to be processed
Set percRng = ActiveSheet.Range("F15:H15") '<== here set the range of % "prizes": they MUST be in ascending order (from lowest to highest)
Set divRng = ActiveSheet.Range("F14:H14") '<== here set the range of the possible divisors. this range MUST be of the same size as thre "prizes" range

For Each cell In dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

    value = cell.value
    nDivisors = 0
    prize = 0
    totalPrize = 0
    Do
        i = FindMaxDivisor(value, percRng, divRng)
        If i > 0 Then
            value = value - divRng(i) ' update value to the remainder
            prize = percRng(i) * divRng(i) ' get current "prize"
            totalPrize = totalPrize + prize 'update totalprize
            nDivisors = nDivisors + 1 'update divisors number
            cell.Offset(, nDivisors) = divRng(i)  'write divisor in next blank adjacent cell in the number row
        End If
    Loop While value > 0 And i >= 0

    If i >= 0 Then ' the number has been correctly divided by given divisors
        With cell.Offset(, nDivisors + 1)
            .value = totalPrize
            .Font.Color = vbRed
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Not possible to break " & cell.value & " into given divisors"
    End If

Next cell

End Sub


Function FindMaxDivisor(value As Long, percRng As Range, divRng As Range) As Long
Dim i As Long

FindMaxDivisor = -1 'default value should not be found any whole divisor

i = divRng.Columns.Count
Do While value Mod divRng(i) <> 0 And i > 1
    i = i - 1
Loop

If value Mod divRng(i) = 0 Then FindMaxDivisor = i

End Function
```

each number "best" divisors will be written in columns next to the number and in the last one there'll be written the "total prize" in red